# Warning label on accepted answers the community doesn't agree with

Tags: feature-request, questions, accepted-answer

On questions in which the community heavily up votes a non-accepted answer, the best we can hope is a user scrolls down far enough to see it.

I propose we go one step further and place a banner on top of a low voted accepted answer that states the community doesn't agree. This is similar to how we require warning labels on cigarette cartons.

I would rather see the "accepted answer" feature be removed and let the up vote down vote ratio do the sorting. So I made this request sort of as just another solution in the realm of possibility. It wouldn't be a great UI decision either, so I hope this doesn't go any further than inspire other ideas.

Comment: "Far down enough"? It's just one answer down.

Comment: @muru sometimes a long answer with a long comment trail makes for a long scroll especially on a mobile device

Comment: @PolyGeo sometimes, yes. But more often I see mods step in and move the chatter to the chatroom.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How can the community "not agree" that the author's personal choice was the *most helpful* to them specifically?

Wait. What?

### Sarcasm: OFF

**I say that ⤴ full of *sarcasm*** because this UI gaff has confounded users since day one. The 'accepted answer' is supposed to indicate (nothing more than) which answer helped the original author specifically… but when accepting an answer sorts it to the top of the list, it doesn't say that at all.

#### When one "vote" counts more than the rest

The entire premise of Stack Exchange is that the **top-voted** answer rises to the top, so when one user overrides all that, the community suddenly feels slighted when the <quote, unquote> *"wrong answer"* sits up there prominently.

I don't blame them.

Requests after request after request after request has suggested various ways to ***fix*** or to ***override*** this personal choice that is the author's to make. Even the tool tip gets this wrong saying that little green check mark was selected as the *best answer.*

**When will we decide the 'accepted answer' shouldn't affect the sort order at all?**

It makes me sad when it looks like we're *resolving* threads as *"We're done here; no more help is needed."* That is ***not*** what Stack Exchange is about, but that is what the UI suggests.

Sort the 'accepted answers' just like any other answer. Yes, we can indicate that the author is thanking a particular user for a post that helped them specifically (mark it with the ✓ check mark or whatever); but criminy already… sort that answer with the rest.

Comment: This aligned with my thoughts, thank you.

Comment: Keep the check mark, but let up/down vote ratio do the sorting.

Comment: It's pretty common that the community rises a wrong, or at least suboptimal, answer to the top. The accepted answer mechanism is the only thing we have to at least allow the best answer to rise to the top. If that went away, we would need this feature even more, to make sure that readers don't stop at the first, highly upvoted, but bad answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. The upvote/downvote ratio (post score) should be enough. There are already proposals to let the accepted answer sort just as normal answers according to their number of votes. That is a far better option than this one is. The accepted answer means just that the original question author liked that one best. Nothing more.

Also, such banner would require another voting mechanism to show agreement or disagreement with it. This is effectively the same as the current way we vote on answers, so this proposal adds nothing new.

Answer (score 2):

> I propose we go one step further and place a banner on top of a ***low voted*** accepted answer that states ***the community doesn't agree***

The keywords are bolded. The community disagrees by downvoting.